# Moving Files between folders by Name Match using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a question and if someone can lead me to the right post, or help me with this

let me show you my main folder

```
Main Folder
|
+---Source \New Folder 1
|       (1)A.txt
|       (1)A1.txt
|       (2)B.txt
|       (2)B2.txt
|       (3)C.txt
|       (3)C3.txt
|
\---Target \New Folder 2
    |
    +---Folder 1
    |       (1)A.txt
    |       (2)B.txt
    |       (3)C.txt
    |
    +---Folder 2
    |       (1)A1.txt
    |
    \---Folder 3
        |
        \---Folder A
            (2)B2.txt
            (3)C3.txt
```

I read over `xcopy`, `robocopy`, but don't think that will have the answer

So let me Explain 
In `Source Folder` I have over 1000 *.txt files with `NO folders`, and in `Target Folder` I have the exact same files, `BUT` all the files are located in folders and Sub-Folders, What I'm trying to do is to replace the files in `Target Folder` with the files in `Source Folder. This has has nothing to do with the` FOLDER NAME`found in the`Target Folder`.

I was provided this script by Jerry, and a link Thank you Jerry

```
for %%a in (Source Folder Name\*.*) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "Target Folder Name\%%~nxa" 2^>nul') do (
        echo copy "%%a" "%%b"
    )
)
```

Now I put this together

Now I have a working script

```
@echo off

Set "Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Folder\New folder (2)\New Folder 1\New folder 1"
Set "target=C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Folder\New folder (2)\New Folder 1\New folder 2"

for %%S in ("New Folder 1\*.*") do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%T in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "New Folder 2\%%~nxS" 2^>nul') do (
        copy "%%S" "%%T"
    )
)
```

Comment: I have once again tried to correct your tree structure. Please let us know if it is correct, and please, in future, use `%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com "Main Folder" /F` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com "Main Folder" /F /A`, and paste it into the question body, instead. Could you also please confirm whether you're wanting to "move the files from `Source` to `Target`", or move the files from `Source` to `Target\Folder 1`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and yes move from source to target, and in target I have over 60 folders, with over 400 sub folders, and in source I will have over 1000.txt files and all have their own file name, I need it to find a match in the target folder or sub folders, and replace the old file with the new source file

Comment: COPY, XCOPY and even ROBOCOPY would not help you solve this issue.  Essentially what I would attempt to do is iterate the files in the target directory and then use an `IF..EXIST` to see if they are in the source.

Comment: @JavierRivas, I am sure since you have been apart of this community, you have seen several us say, "StackOverFlow is not a code writing service!"  If you do not attempt to write some code your question will be closed.

Comment: I just looked back at a few of your most recent questions.  All the code that you would need to do what I described in my first comment, you have already coded yourself in previous batch files.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do - you want to move a file from the source to whatever folder under target where it is already located?  Regardless of the names of the subfolders under Target?  So the Target subfolder names have nothing to do with this?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Yes, The folder and sub folder names have nothing to do with, it must find the `filename` from `source` and find the same `filename in target` and `replace it` with the `source files`, the search is based on file name

Comment: in my search I find how to move files based on folder names, but can't find how to move files by filename.txt to filename.txt, ignoring folder name, Both `Source` and `Target` have the exact same files, but the `Source has updated content`, and I need to replace the matching files in target folder, but I have over 1000 .txt files easy and need to place them back in their original folders, opening every folder and sub folder to find the matching files would take forever

Comment: if you noticed in my source folder each file has their own name, and the original (Target) folders also has the same files, it will match based on file name, it will search and find the same file name in target folder, and replace it with the files in Source, I hope that helps

Comment: I have posted an answer.  Please let me know if you need a break down of how it works.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Thank you I'm looking at it, did you get it to work, I feel like it needs `Set Source and Target`, I'm testing it

Comment: In your previous questions, including this one there have been several code examples of how to iterate all the files or a subset of files in a directory but you continue to hard code a single file or use a single argument as your input.  You need to understand these basic concepts before you can do these higher level tasks like you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Is it that I called my source directory `source` and my target directory `target` and they are spelled differently than what you called them?  If so, rename the directories in my answer.  Is it because I am echoing the copy command to the screen instead of just actually doing the copy?  I did that so that I could see what it was doing - if I just did the copy then I wouldn't get to see what it was doing.  If that's the problem then remove the `echo` bit from the copy command.  If it is something else then you need to describe how it doesn't work in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  I'm not an expert at batch files so there is probably a better way, but this seems to work:

```
@echo off
for %%S in (New Folder 1\*.*) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%T in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "New Folder 2\%%~nxS" 2^>nul') do (
        copy "%%S" "%%T"
    )
)
```

I adapted this updated code from https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/469260-batch-file-to-search-and-copy-files-spesified-in-txt-file because it is almost exactly the same question.

Comment: @JavierRivas I am trying to understand how you don't understand how this works.  I have looked at all of your previous batch file questions and this code is pretty straight forward compared to your other questions.  The source and target folder paths are just pseudo hard coded examples.  You don't need to use variables for everything.  Either hard code your paths in place of source and target or create your variables like you do in your other questions.  This essentially tells me that you really are not understanding any of the code you have been given in previous questions.

Comment: @JavierRivas So, the first for loop assigns each file in `source\*.*` to the variable `%%S`, one at a time.  Then the second for loop runs `dir /b /s /a:-d` in the `target` directory for the filename in `%%S` and assigns the file it found into `%%T`  Now that we have the source file (`%%S`) and the target file (`%%T`) we can run the copy command.  I made a `source` and `target` directory with a structure similar to what you had in the question and it worked fine for me, so I don't understand what the problem is that you are having.

Comment: Weird OK, I'll see what I did wrong, Thanks Jerry

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Thanks for the break down, I do understand the way it reads, what throw me off was that `SET` are missing and `Source and Target` do not have the `%%` around those words, and the placement of the directory. So I updated my question to see if I set it up correctly, since you said you got it to work and mine still fails

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I got it working, when you used `Source` and `Target` that got me confused, I thought those were apart of the `Set Source` and `Set Target` directories. I have it as `Source Folder` in my question, and `Target Folder` Well Thank you very much